# run cron from 5am to mightnight, every 30minutes, everyday

Tags: php, nginx, centos, cron

I was able to generate this directive with some help
As I'm not a cron expert by any means.

What I expect it to do is:
Run every 30 minutes from
5 AM to Midnight, every day

```
0,30 0,5-23 * * * /path_to_script
```

Even if it's correct, is this the right syntax to do it? Or it doesn't matter
because I haven't seen "," before in crons, just "/"

Comment: This will also run at `00:30`, do you really want that?

Comment: Read `man 5 crontab` for full details on crontab syntax.

Comment: I want it to run every 30 minutes from 05:00 to 12:00
But it would not hurt even it if ran once at 12:30

Comment: Then it's the correct syntax.

Comment: If you didn't want it to run at `00:30`, you would need to use two separate entries. One for `0,30 5-23`, another for `0 0`.

Comment: 30 5-23 * * *

Or this?

Comment: That would run at `5:30, 6:30, 7:30, etc.`, but not at `5:00, 6:00, 7:00`.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, but it will also run at `00:30`. If you don't want that, you need two entries.

```
0,30 5-23 * * * /path_to_script
0 0 * * * /path_to_script
```

Comment: Thank you Bamar. It's not  a bad thing if it runs at 00:30.
I just wanted to avoid other unnecessary runs during the night.

Comment: Why would it run other times during the night? They're not in the range 5-23.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid cron expressions that might be confusing to me at a later time. Just because It will run once at 00:30, is not a big problem for my project. So I think I will end up using just one expression even if it
runs at 00:30